# Rails append type to join table with has_many :through and association extensions

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have an AR association with extensions in Rails similar to the example presented in this link:
[ActiveRecord Association Extensions](http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/activerecord-association-extensions/)

```
has_many :issues, :through => :qbert_issues do
  def tracking
    where("qbert_issues.kind = ?", "tracking")
  end

  def blocking
    where("qbert_issues.kind = ?", "blocking")
  end
end
```

As shown above, mine is multi-typed... I need to populate a 'kind' column in my join table.  Ideally, this should just work:

```
q = QBert.find(123)
q.issues.tracking << Issue.find(234)
```

So, what the article suggests is overloading `<<` and doing something like this:

```
has_many :issues, ... do
  ...
  def <<(issue)
    issue.kind = "UserAccount"
    proxy_association.owner.issues += [issue]
  end
end
```

Which would be nice, if kind was static.

It looks like I can do this...

```
has_many :issues, ... do
  ...
  def <<(*args)
    issue, kind = args.flatten
    issue.kind = kind
    proxy_association.owner.issues += [issue]
  end
end
```

Which would allow me to do this at the very least:

```
q = QBert.find(123)
q.issues.tracking << [Issue.find(234), :tracking]
```

That doesn't seem very DRY to me...is there a better way?  Bonus points if you take into account that the kind accessor is off a join table `qbert_issues`.  I'm guessing I just have to add the association manually through the `QBertIssue` model directly.

Comment: I found the answer that I was looking for, but I'm looking for alternative techniques as well.  I'll move the checkmark around for better implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
def <<(issue)
  kind = where_values.second.scan(/kind = '(.*)'/).flatten.first
  left = proxy_association.reflection.source_reflection
  right = proxy_association.reflection.through_reflection

  left.active_record.create(left.foreign_key.to_sym => issue.id, 
                            right.foreign_key.to_sym => proxy_association.owner.id, 
                            :kind => kind)
end
```

Which lets me do:

```
q = QBert.find(123)
q.issues.tracking << Issue.find(234)
```

It could be made sufficiently generalized by parsing out the `where_values` and merging them into the parameters hash.

`Pry` rocks, by the way :D

Comment: Do you have any references for how you got this solution?

Comment: I figured it out by leafing through the documentation and a few other Rails websites while code golfing inside of a Pry session.  If I had a link that lead me to the solution I have forgotten it :D

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've found some solutions (they're quite simple actually), so if I have any updates, I'll let you know